# Не работает атрибут download в браузере Chrome

Tags: html

```
<a href="kartinka.jpg" download> Скачать картинку </a>
<a href="kartinka.jpg" download="kartinka.jpg"> Скачать картинку </a>
```

Оба варианта не работают, Google Chrome последняя версия

Comment: Код?11 символов нужно...

Comment: А у меня оба варианта работают. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы они перестали работать, как у вас?